# Iterar en método toString() sobreescrito

Tags: java, string, iteradores

Tengo dentro de un método el siguiente código:

```
    System.out.println("CANT.\t\tPRODUCTO\t\tPRECIO UD.\t\tTOTAL"+ "\n====\t\t========\t\t========\t\t====");
        
        Iterator it = listado.iterator();       
        while(it.hasNext()) { 
            System.out.println(it.next());
            
        }           
        System.out.println("\nTOTAL--------------->"+getImporteTotal());
```

"listado" es un HashSet donde he ido añadiendo objetos.

En vez de imprimir desde el método donde agrego los objetos a "listado", quiero hacerlo sobreescribiendo en el método toString(), ya que necesitaré hacer lo mismo cuando también quiera eliminar algún objeto del HashSet.

No tengo claro cómo imprimir múltiples líneas en toString(), ya que creo que sólo puedo usar un return. ¿Alguna pista sobre cómo implementar ese código en toString()?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes indicar los saltos de línea que quieras en el String que retornas. Algo del estilo de

```
public String toString(){ 
    return String.format( var1 + "%n " + var2 + "%n " + varN);
}
```

Para asociarlo a la iteración, puedes usar un StringBuilder e ir haciendo append de cada elemento concatenado con `"%n"` al final.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. He podido darle una solución con los métodos get/set y luego concatenando los get en el método toString.

Comment: Lo mejor es que pongas tu propia respuesta como respuesta, la marques como aceptada y así todos sepan cómo resolviste tu pregunta! :D

Answer (score 1):

Vendría a ser algo así:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getVeces()+"\t\t"+getNombre()+"\t\t"+getPrecio()+"\t\t\t"+getSubtotal();
}
```